# Make object move toward a position with a overshot effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm trying to make an object moved to a position, but, depending on the speed it's going, I want it to overhoot it's target and bounce back to it.

This is how I'm moving the object toward the other now:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp (transform.position, blackhole.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 25f);
}
```

This obviously doesn't account for the "overshoot" effect. However I've been having trouble to achieve it, since when trying with physics all my attempts end up with my object orbiting indefinitely around it's target, instead of passing it just once and moving inside it.

Comment: You could look at the target destination as a gravity source, with the moving object having an actual velocity that changes on each update, in addition to moving the object by the velocity. Imagine an actual physical object with a gravity force. The physics in unity might include such behavior; worth a check.

Comment: Also, bounce is a misleading term here. You're trying to get a sling-shot/overshoot effect.

Comment: [Could be useful](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/return-to-position-but-overshoot.154335/) (sry for multiple comments)

Comment: I tried to use the physics in Unity. My problem is that the closest thing I ended up having object1 orbit around object2 indefinitely. It seems I need to do something special so it doesn't keep constantly "overshooting" the target, but only overshoots it once.

Comment: Is that also the behavior of the algorithm in the maybe-useful link from the comment above?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could go about this. Nathan's suggestion of using "gravity" by applying forces every step I'll call the "Physics" solution. Your current solution that simply sets position I'll call the "Tweening" solution. Both can certainly work, and both can benefit from simply using if statements. For both solutions, stop the "orbiting" or head back from overShootPos with simple checks.

For Tweening:
When the move first starts, start tweening to a position past where you actually want to be.

```
Vector3 overShootPos = destinationPos + (destinationPos-transform.position)*overShootPercentage;
```

Then in FixedUpdate:

```
float deltaP = 0.001f;
if((transform.position-overShootPos).magnitude<deltaP){
    //start tweening to destinationPos rather than overShootPos. Possibly just
    overShootPos = destinationPos;
}
```

For Physics:
The forces actually will take the object past the destination, and it may start "orbiting" like you were saying.
In FixedUpdate, stop it once it's close and slow enough:

```
float deltaP = 1f; //may want larger delta here since physics is less precise.
if((transform.position-destinationPos).magnitude<deltaP && rb.velocity.magnitude<deltaP){
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    transform.position = destinationPos;
}
```

This is not all the code, but the basic idea should work.

Also, consider some of the differences between Physics and Tweening solutions (that may include code other than this). The Tweening will be very precise, and work basically the same way every time, where the Physics one may scale more crazily with large distances/fast speeds. The Physics solution is clearly needed if you do want the object to respond to explosions, collisions, etc.. on its route to the destination. If you go with Tweening, consider looking at tweening libraries like iTween and DOTween, especially if you'll be using a lot of tweens. They'll be faster (less Updates) and provide a nice syntax for doing stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a basic spring system. Equation of a spring

F = k(x-l) (Force = Spring Constant * (Extension - Rest Length)

So to calculate the spring force on your body:

Force = SpringConstant * (PointToHeadTo - CurrentPosition)

You then either use the physics damping in your engine or you apply your own damping

D = Velocity * -DampingConstant (DampingForce = Velocity * -DampingConstant)

Which you then apply as a force. However Unity / UE4 have damping co-efficients you set so you just need the spring force.

To keep things stable you can limit the Spring Force to a maximum and only have it take effect when within a radius of the target. You can also ramp up the damping as you cross the target to help bring it to rest.